# Windows 10 search box is broken after doing a system restore

Tags: windows, search, restore

I recently had a problem when I installed a software and thought that I will restore this pc to a restore point which I created when I first got my new PC. My PC is a Dell Inspiron 3471 with 8GB ram Intel i5 9400. After doing the restore I saw that my search box appears broken and Microsoft store apps don't work correctly.

I have tried cleaning temporary files and cache. I have restarted my computer thrice but nothing worked. I also ran the sfc /scannow and the DISM /online /restorehealth command but it doesn't help me at all. Please help me with this search box because it's so annoying to be with this kind of search box all the time. I have also checked for updates and installed them but did not fix the issue. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Please correct my English if I am wrong.

Operating System - Windows 10 Home 64 Bit 21h1
[Here is the image of this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZqQd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You state: "restore this pc to a restore point which I created when I first got my new PC." Was that days ago or *years* ago? Unless you restore a full disk *image* e.g., one created with third-party software such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/), as opposed to Windows System restore, your machine will be in an inconsistent state. For example, the Registry (or at least parts of it) would have been restored to its original state, but the old Registry has no settings for new items added through Windows update, nor for new software.

The best thing to do at this point is to create Windows 10 reinstallation media [from an ISO image](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-an-iso-file-for-windows-10-38547366-1dcb-7afd-1726-9eb222d72705) downloaded from Microsoft using their [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Select *Download tool now* and follow directions to reinstall Windows, while *keeping your files*.

Comment: I also seem to remember this bug from a previous release of Windows 10.  I am seriously wondering if he doesn't have bits and pieces from that release (with nothing to back that suspicion up but behavior).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, exactly: the system is in an inconsistent state, and should be reinstalled.

Comment: I totally agree with you.  I wasn't trying to say anything else.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answers. I figured what was causing this thing. It's because of the new News and interests spam in the taskbar. When I enable that stuff the search box becomes normal but when I disable it the search box becomes broken like an egg again. Right-click on your taskbar and enable news and interests. I have kept showing icon only because the text was spamming my taskbar.